# Need to have some method to access data in my class

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public static class ReferenceData
{

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDatastore()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "DEV", Text = "Development"  },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "DC1", Text = "Production" },
            };
    }
}
```

When I want to find the name of the datastore given the value I have been using:

```
DatastoreText = ReferenceData.GetDatastore().Single(s => s.Value == datastoreValue).Text
```

This works good but is there a better way? Can I code the above into my reference class and so reuse it in different places?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just put that code in a method with a value types property...

```
public static string GetDatastoreText(string datastoreValue)
{
    return ReferenceData.GetDatastore().Single(s => s.Value == datastoreValue).Text;
}
```

or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` to make it faster and surround access in method like musefan said.

Comment: If possible can you provide me with an example. Even just a few lines would be great. Sorry my knowledge of C# is not so good. I have ideas but always find others have better ones :-(

Answer (score 0):

You are creating and returning a new array each time you access the property. Is this really your intention (seeing that you initialize all data in code)? If not, you should use a private field for your data.

Also, you could use a Dictionary for your data, so you could access it by the Value like this:

```
ReferenceData.GetDataStore()[datastoreValue]
```